# Getting second derivative of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to understand the homework example the professor gave to me. What do I require to do, is to find the inflection points of the following differential equation:
$$
y' = \frac{x}{3y}
$$

Here's his logic behind this:
Since y'' = 0 is the necessary (yet not sufficient) condition for the inflection point to exist, we differentiate both sides of the equation:
$$
y'' = \frac{y-xy'}{3y^2}
$$

What I cannot understand is how did he get this result. Since second derivative of function is the derivative of it's derivative, shouldn't it be the following?
$$
y' = \dfrac{x}{3y}
$$
$$
y'' = \left(\dfrac{x}{3y}\right)' = -\dfrac{x}{3y^2}
$$

Can someone please explain how did he get that result? It feels like I'm kinda missing some point behind the differential equation's differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sides of the ODE are differentiated with respect to the variable $x$, so what you're supposed to compute is
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{x}{3 y(x)} \right)
.
$$
But you're computing
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \frac{x}{3 y} \right)
,
$$
which is something completely different.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Yeah, it's all clear now.